# cucumber watir launch website

Tags: automation, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

On a windows 7 machine, I followed the install from below link, and all worked out well.
 http://www.spritecloud.com/2011/04/complete-setup-guide-for-ruby-cucumber-and-watir-or-selenium-on-windows/

Now on my windows 8.1 machine following same steps, it is not behaving as it should;

```
C:\Users\paul.omahony\Documents\features>cucumber
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - features. You can use `cucumber --init` to get started.
```

When I run

```
C:\Users\paul.omahony\Documents\features>cucumber test.feature
Feature: test website navigation
        Navigate through the different taps on homepage
```

And step/features come back as undefined. It seems that cucumber is not picking up any of the step definitions that I have in the step definition file. This is my Gem List below

```
bigdecimal (default: 1.2.
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.11.2)
childprocess (0.5.9)
cucumber (2.3.3)
cucumber-core (1.4.0)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
ffi (1.9.10 x64-mingw32)
gherkin (4.0.0, 3.2.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.
json (default: 1.8.3)
minitest (5.8.3)
multi_json (1.11.2)
multi_test (0.1.2)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
power_assert (0.2.6)
psych (default: 2.0.17)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (default: 4.2.1)
rspec (3.4.0)
rspec-core (3.4.4)
rspec-expectations (3.4.0
rspec-mocks (3.4.1)
rspec-support (3.4.1)
rubygems-update (2.6.3)
rubyzip (1.2.0)
selenium-webdriver (2.53.
test-unit (3.1.5)
watir-scroll (0.1.0)
watir-webdriver (0.9.1)
websocket (1.2.3)
win32console (1.3.2)
```

I think it maybe a configuration/compatibility issue, but apart from that. I'm not really to sure.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the `cucumber` command, it expects there to be a "features" directory within the current directory. In other words, you want to run the command from the parent of "features" directory not from within the "features" directory.

More specifically, run `cucumber` from "C:\Users\paul.omahony\Documents".

```
C:\Users\paul.omahony\Documents>cucumber
```

Comment: HI Justin, thanks for ur answer, when running cucumber cmd. The "error is cannot load such file --ffi_c (LoadError). Gem set is the same as above.

Comment: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10-x64-mingw32/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'

Comment: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10-x64-mingw32/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'

Comment: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10-x64-mingw32/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'

Comment: Is this a compatibility issue??

Comment: It is possible that the FFI gem does not yet support Ruby 2.3. Based on [Issue 493](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/pull/493), support for Ruby 2.3 was fixed a couple of weeks ago, but has not yet been released.

Comment: the other possibility is that the FFI stuff did not build properly.  Did you install 'DevKit' (https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) when you installed ruby?  I think that's one of those gems that compiles locally when installing.  you could try un-installing and re-installing that gem.

Comment: Not sure how useful this datapoint is, but I'm running ruby 2.3 and watir-webdriver, and Cucumber and the same version of the FFi gem on a mac and so far I get no errors like you are on Win8..

Comment: HI, thank you for ur comments, I have dev kit installed, I have uninstalled FFi gem and reinstalled,but the  same problem persists. I have also tried installing using "gem install ffi --platform=ruby" but to no avail!

Answer (score 0):

i came across some issues installing Ruby on windows 8.1, never the less i was able to work through them by using Ruby and devkit windows installers from here:

https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

**Note: make sure to uninstall Runby and devkit, and delete the Ruby directory as well to start Fresh. Also make sure you match the Ruby and Devkit version/64bit vs 32bit, keep track of your steps, if it doesn't work, start fresh and do something different, good luck man.**